# create array, add to multi deminsional inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have something like this:

```
$target = array();
foreach($ugczfips as $area)
{
  $temp = array('state' => $area['state'], 'zone' => $area['zone']);
  $target[] = $temp;
}
```

Of course, the problem is that every loop overwrites the previous contents of $temp so the data gets lost.

What's the correct way to do this?

It seems like one would need: `$target = new array();` but that doesn't work!

Comment: It doesn't get lost as you add it to $target... What's the problem?

Comment: Why is this a problem? $temp is supposed to be temporary, no? Why do you care what happens to $temp if you get all the data with $target?

Comment: You don't even need $temp:  `$target[] = array('state' => $area['state'], 'zone' => $area['zone']);`

Comment: Also you're missing a ; at the first line

Comment: Michael, you're correct... I figured it out about 10 minutes after I asked the question.

Comment: @ppetree why not close the question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael provided the correct answer:

```
$temp: $target[] = array('state' => $area['state'], 'zone' => $area['zone']);
```